Class initialization must not depend on services
I am attempting to run Android Studio for the first time on Ubuntu 20.24 and the console looks like this
$ ./studio.sh 
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
2024-08-29 05:23:53,006 [    764]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlags <clinit> requests com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlagSettings instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
2024-08-29 05:23:53,396 [   1154]   WARN - #c.i.n.i.NotificationGroupManagerImpl - Notification group Logcat is already registered (group=com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup@5f346e6). Plugin descriptor: PluginDescriptor(name=Android, id=org.jetbrains.android, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=/usr/local/android-studio/plugins/android, version=241.18034.62.2411.12169540, package=null, isBundled=true)
2024-08-29 05:23:54,043 [   1801]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.CodeStyleSettings$DefaultsHolder <clinit> requests com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.CodeStyleSettingsService instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
2024-08-29 05:23:54,057 [   1815]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.CodeStyleSettings$DefaultsHolder <clinit> requests com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.LanguageCodeStyleSettingsProviderService instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.

The installation process freezes at this point.
Any idea how to fix this?
